# What is the use of SagaIterator from '@redux-saga/core'

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

What is the use of `SagaIterator` in a function generator?

```js
import { SagaIterator } from '@redux-saga/core'

function* getCountry(action: ReturnType<typeof actions.country.request>) : SagaIterator {
    try {       
        const selectedCountry = (state: models.InitialStateTypes) => state.selectedCountryInitial        
        const data = yield select(selectedCountry)       
        const response: AxiosResponse<models.CountryInitialResponse> = yield call(
            axios.get , 
            'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${data}' , 
            { 
                params: action.payload 
            }
        );
        yield put(actions.country.success(response.data))
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(actions.country.failure(error))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, we can see a comment from the authors:

```
/**
 * Annotate return type of generators with `SagaIterator` to get strict
 * type-checking of yielded effects.
 */
export type SagaIterator = IterableIterator<StrictEffect>
```

And just a quick look at the definition for StrictEffect:

```
export type StrictEffect<T = any> = SimpleEffect<T, any> | StrictCombinatorEffect<T>

export interface StrictCombinatorEffect<T> extends CombinatorEffect<T, StrictEffect<T>> {}

export interface SimpleEffect<T, P> {
  '@@redux-saga/IO': true
  combinator: false
  type: T
  payload: P
}
```

So what it says is that the generator yields redux-saga Effects like put, call, select, etc. This means that if you try to yield something else in your generator you should get a compile error from Typescript